# Neo4j ValueRepresentation value

Tags: java, neo4j

How can I get the original string value (`someString`) from instance of `org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ValueRepresentation` created by this code as a return of server-plugin:

```
return ValueRepresentation.string(someString)
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you need that for?

Probably use serialize, pass in a `RepresentationFormat` that just passes on the value as result in its `serializeValue` method.

```
ValueRepresentation {
  String serialize( RepresentationFormat format, URI baseUri, ExtensionInjector extensions )
    {
        final String result = format.serializeValue(type, value);
        format.complete();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks! I've seen this method (the only one with access to `value`), but do not understand how I can use it with my data (I'm quite new to Java, sorry). I write functional tests for Neo4j plug-in. Maybe there are more convenient ways to test, I'm trying to figure out.